# Adding columns and rows to tale by input - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

the table in default is 3x3 (3 rows & 3 columns).
If the user writes in input 7, the table needs to be changed into 7x7 table.

What I did in the code is first adding the rows (working successfully), and then adding to every row cells/columns - But this is not working for some reason.

Thanks for help !

Relevant code:

```
    <main>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>

<input id="tableSizeInput" type="text" placeholder="enter number">
            <button id="tableSizeButton">Set</button>
```

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 70vh;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}

td {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```
tableSizeButton.onclick = function () {
                let counter = 0;
                while(counter!=parseInt(tableSizeInput.value))
                {
                    let row = table.insertRow(0);
                    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

                    counter++;
                }

                for (let b = 0; b<table.rows.length; b++)
                {
                    for(let i = 3; i<parseInt(tableSizeInput.value)-3; i++)
                       {
                           table.rows[b].insertCell(i);
                       }
                }
```

Comment: The counter needs to start at `3`, or there will be 3 rows too many. `i` otoh needs to start at `0`, or there will be 3 columns too few.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

I spotted 2 things missing:

1/

```
<main>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
```

2/

```
 let counter = 0;
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 while (counter != parseInt(tableSizeInput.value)) {
```

That should get you adding extra rows

Answer (score 0):

using this method, i mean inserting rows and then cell for that row,
i don't think that u can insert cells for already existing rows. 
   So u cant make 3x3 table to be 7x7 by insertRow/Cell method but u can make 3x3 table to become 3x7 or even 7x7 BUT in that case first 3 row wil not have cells. 
P.s make sure to add css with td,tr borders if u run this code

```
    <body>


            <table id="tt">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <script>

     function a()
    {

    var v=document.getElementById('i1').value;
    parseInt(v);

    var table=document.getElementById('tt');

    for (var i = 0; i < v-3; i++) {
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

    for (var l = 0; l < v; l++) {
          var cell = row.insertCell(l);
    }

    }

    }
    </script>
            <input id="i1" type="text">
            <input id="b1" onclick="a();" type="button">
    </body>
```